# How to use Chef::Resource::CookbookFile from HWRP?

Tags: chef-infra

When I use cookbook_file resource from recipe, it works as expected

```
cookbook_file 'd:/temp/test.txt' do
   source 'text.txt'
end
```

When trying to make same from HWRP action using following code

```
cbfile = Chef::Resource::CookbookFile.new('d:/temp/test.txt', run_context)
cbfile.source('text.txt')
cbfile.run_action(:create)
```

it fails with error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: cookbook_file[text.txt] (dynamically defined) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook  not found.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSL does a bunch more stuff than your manual code. Most pertinently to this is setting `@cookbook_name` which is used to find the cookbook to look for the file. That said, you can use the DSL just fine from an "HWRP" and I would recommend it as we don't promise the internals of the DSL will remain stable over time.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you were meaning when saying 'you can use the DSL just fine from "HWRP"'?
My HWRP resides in library folder along with resource and I do not find a way to use DSL inside "pure ruby class".
There is Module: `Chef::DSL::Resources` but it is marked as private and along with it is text: "**This module is part of a private API**. You should avoid using this module if possible, as it may be removed or be changed in the future."

Comment: HWRP means you have two normal Ruby classes, one that inherits from `Chef::Resource` and one from `Chef::Provider`. You can also inherit from the `LWRPBase` version of one or both, which provides some of the same helpers as the LWRP system. `Chef::Provider::LWRPBase` pulls in the DSL for you, or if you subclass `Chef::Provider` directly you can `include Chef::DSL::Recipe`. In either case, you can use the normal recipe DSL in your action method like you would in an LWRP.

Comment: About HWRP, yes, I have those classes.

Comment: I subclass `Chef::Provider`and tried second path.
My code:
`declare_resource(:cookbook_file, ::File.join(@new_resource.folder, @new_resource.name), caller[0]) do
            source @new_resource.name
          end`
which does not work.
Checking chef source I found.
`resource_builder` invokes `instance_eval` on resource (`cookbok_file`) and passes block defined in my resource (which has reference to instance variables).
Accessing variables cause exception.
How to share instance variable of my resource in block executed in scope of invoking resource?

Comment: When I say "use the DSL" I don't mean "use the internal methods of the DSL". See https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd/blob/master/libraries/httpd_config_debian.rb#L6-L14 for an example, just use the **actual** DSL system.

Comment: This is second approach you were offering in you answer. It is not exactly what I was trying to do. Showed example implements action in resource file. I was trying to create subclass of Provider and do code there.
Nevertheless, I modified my code and moved implementation of action from Provider to Resource.
Thanks for link.
Out of curiosity: Still wondering how to capture context and pass it to code block (you proposed to subclass Provider).
`declare_resource(:cookbook_file, ::File.join(@new_resource.folder, `@new_resource.name), caller[0]) do`
`  source @new_resource.name`
`end`